# A murder in the Puzznk rock band

Tags: cipher, story, mystery

**There has been a murder!**

Crazy Dan, one of the members of the Puzznk rock band, was found dead on the ground after a wild party with the other band members last Saturday. He didn't die of an overdose either: he had a knife sticking out of his back.

Detective Inspector Jorkins is in charge of the investigation; her officers have arrested the other three band members - Mad Jason, Drunken Carl, and Jumpy Mick - and brought them in for questioning. But the alcohol and drugs must have addled their heads, and none of them is able to give a coherent story of what happened on the night of the murder.

Mad Jason says:

> I dunno, man. We was talkin' about the big performance we had planned in Tokyo in a few years' time. Dan was yellin' about what a flop it was gonna be - said the date was unlucky. I dunno what's wrong with 19/11/20, but he was goin' on about how the only reason the Berlin one went so well was that it was on 11/03/08. Loada rubbish if you ask me.

Drunken Carl says:

> Yeah, that was one hell of a party. Haven't been so stoned since our American tour in 2005, when we had a gig in Caracas on the 9th of August and then one in New York on the 18th of September. And already we'd hardly recovered from the one in Hong Kong on the 12th of December the previous year. This Saturday night was a blur - I don't remember nothing of what Dan did.

Jumpy Mick says:

> I'll always remember Dan as he was in our last really big show, in Lisbon. It was June the 12th last year, and he was magnificent. The year before that, we was in London on April the 5th, but that weren't such a good year. Oh, I remember! His finest hour was way back in 2009, October the 9th I think it was. We had a great time in Sydney - don't think I've ever seen Dan so happy since.

Jorkins is stumped. She can't work out which of the men is guilty of the murder of Crazy Dan.

### **Can you identify the killer?**

<sub>Note: I write dates in dd/mm/yy form. Hints will be added if necessary.</sub>

**Hint 1:**

> this puzzle doesn't reflect a realistic scenario, and isn't solvable 'in-universe'. The solution involves putting together parts of all three men's testimonies in the correct order so that an enciphered message emerges.

Comment: Maybe maps are needed again....

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The killer is:

> Mad Jason

**Step 1: Ordering**

> First, take all of the exact dates mentioned, and order them alphabetically by location. You get:
>
>  
>       `11/03/08: Berlin
>       09/08/05: Caracas
>       12/12/04: Hong Kong
>       12/06/15: Lisbon
>       05/04/14: London
>       18/09/05: New York
>       09/10/09: Sydney
>       19/11/20: Tokyo`

**Step 2: Substitution**

> Now substitute letters into the date. For the day and year, use the position alphabetically (1=A, etc.). For the month, use the first letter of that month's name:
>
>  
>     `KMH Berlin
>     IAE Caracas
>     LDD Hong Kong
>     LJO Lisbon
>     EAN London
>     RSE New York
>     IOI Sydney
>     SNT Tokyo`

**Step 3: The Message**

> Now just read each column in order (days, then months, then years), to get the final message:
>
>  `KILLERIS MADJASON HEDONEIT`

Comment: Excellent! Perfect solution.

Comment: @randal'thor I did spend a little while wondering who "Chlfdijk" was...

Comment: You haven't heard of Chlf Dijk, the famous Welshman from a Dutch family?

Answer (score 1):

All mentioned dates:

**12/12/04: Hong Kong**

> Drunk Carl: And already we'd hardly recovered from the one in Hong Kong on the 12th of December the previous year. This Saturday night was a blur - I don't remember nothing of what Dan did.
>   *Note: I'm not completely sure this took place in 2004*

**American Tour 2005**

> Drunk Carl: Yeah, that was one hell of a party. Haven't been so stoned since our American tour in 2005

**09/08/05: Caracas**

> Drunk Carl: when we had a gig in Caracas on the 9th of August and then one in New York on the 18th of September.

**18/09/05: New York**

> Drunk Carl: when we had a gig in Caracas on the 9th of August and then one in New York on the 18th of September.

**11/03/08: Berlin**

> Mad Jason: I dunno what's wrong with 19/11/20, but he was goin' on about how the only reason the Berlin one went so well was that it was on 11/03/08. Loada rubbish if you ask me.

**09/10/09: Sydney**

> Jumpy Micky: Oh, I remember! His finest hour was way back in 2009, October the 9th I think it was. We had a great time in Sydney - don't think I've ever seen Dan so happy since.

**05/04/14: London**

> Jumpy Micky: The year before that, we was in London on April the 5th, but that weren't such a good year.

**12/06/15: Lisbon**

> Jumpy Micky: I'll always remember Dan as he was in our last really big show, in Lisbon. It was June the 12th last year, and he was magnificent

**19/11/20: Tokyo**

> Mad Jason: We was talkin' about the big performance we had planned in Tokyo in a few years' time. Dan was yellin' about what a flop it was gonna be - said the date was unlucky.

**Saturday Night**

> Mad Jason: I dunno, man. We was talkin' about the big performance we had planned in Tokyo in a few years' time.
>   Drunk Carl: This Saturday night was a blur - I don't remember nothing of what Dan did.

---

**Notes:**

> I used OPs date system and for Lisbon/Tokyo I'm not completely sure about the years. Hopefully this helps someone get somewhere. If not I'll tackle it over the weekend.